# Missing form label accessibility error in Kendo combobox

Tags: kendo-ui, accessibility, wai-aria

I need to fix a complaint accessibility issue, that is [missing form label](http://webaim.org/standards/wcag/checklist#sc1.1.1), but as we use kendo, I was wondering if anybody knows if is possible to do it by kendo configuration.

The component in question is a [combobox](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index).

I did a deep search and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to fix the accessibility error in the accessibility report was use some jquery to include two properties: title and aria-label.

```
$({selector}).kendoComboBox({ placeholder: "Search ...",
...

var combobox = $("#header-search .k-input").eq(0);
combobox.attr("title", "Search ...");
combobox.attr("aria-label", "Search ...");
```

I've been used this tool to identify the problem: [wave-evaluation-tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wave-evaluation-tool/jbbplnpkjmmeebjpijfedlgcdilocofh)

Comment: I am using same tool. can you tell me how this issue can be solved for kendo checkbox?